# What is the maximum number of cliques you can add to a graph by adding a vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with at least $k$ vertices.

> What is the maximum number of cliques attainable by adding a vertex
> $v$ to $G$ with $\deg(v)=k$?

My best guess is $2^k$, using the following example:

Let $G$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices and let $k=n-1$. Then adding a vertex to $G$ with degree $k$ adds $2^k$ cliques. (I just did this by drawing examples for small $n$).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. Only as $k$ it is necessary to take $n$, that is, $k=n$.

If we add a vertex $v$ and connect it with all vertices of graph $G$, we obtain a complete graph with $n+1$ vertices.
Now each subset of vertices of graph $G$ together with vertex $v$ forms a new complete graph. Since there are exactly $2^n=2^k$ subsets in the set of $n$ elements, we obtain that the number of additional complete subgraphs is $2^k$.

Can there be more? The answer is 'no'. I think it is almost obvious. But if you doubt it, I'll give you this simple reasoning.